# Swiftで外部クラスからWKWebViewを操作したい

Tags: swift, wkwebview

Swiftの各タブ内にWKWebViewを生成するWebViewアプリを開発しています。
UINavigationControllerとUITabBarControllerを併用していて、上部に共通のヘッダーがあります。
各タブにはそれぞれWKWebViewでWebページを設置していて、Webページ内で違うページに遷移すると上部のヘッダーに戻るボタンを追加します。（アクティブタブが変わればそのWebViewに戻るボタンが必要かどうか判断しています）

Tab毎のViewController内でWebViewが戻るメソッドを用意しています。

```
class Tab1ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!
    ....
    public func webViewGoBack() {
        webView.goBack()
    }
}
```

UITabBarControllerのクラス内で戻るボタンが押された時のActionを設定しています。

```
class TabsViewController: UITabBarController {
    @IBAction func webViewGoBackBtn(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        Tab1ViewController().webViewGoBack()
    }
....
```

アプリはビルドできるのですが、実際にヘッダーのボタンを押してwebViewGoBackを実行するとXcodeで以下のエラーが表示されてアプリがクラッシュします。

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Tab1ViewController内でwebViewGoBack()を実行した時は正常に動きました。
修正方法または解決方法を教えて頂けると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ソース全体が質問に書かれていないので、確実なことは言えませんが、提示されたソースの`@IBAction`部で

```
Tab1ViewController().webViewGoBack()
```

としておられますが、これでは、Tab1ViewControllerを新規に作成し、それに`webViewGoBack`というメソッドを発行していますね。
これでは、作られたての`Tab1ViewController`のインスタンス内の操作すべき`WKWebView`にはまだなにも入っていない(=`nil`)ので、`public func webViewGoBack()`内部の

```
webView.goBack()
```

の`webView`は、まだ`nil`のため出るエラーと思われます。

対応としては、`TabsViewController`の初期化でメンバー変数に`Tab1ViewController`のインスタンスを保存しておき、（当然その中の`webView`も値がちゃんと入る様にし、そのメンバーに対して`webViewGoBack()`メソッドを実行することだと思います。
なので、`Tab1ViewController`の内容は、必要な部分だけ記述しますが

```
class TabsViewController: UITabBarController {
    let tab1: Tab1ViewController = Tab1ViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // tab1の設定が必要であればここで行う
    }

    @IBAction func webViewGoBackBtn(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        tab1.webViewGoBack()
    }
}
```

と、なるべきだと思います。